# Liferay 7 (DXP) Spring MVC portlet, issue accessing service builder generated services

Tags: spring, liferay, liferay-service-builder, liferay-dxp

I am facing issue while accessing services (generated through service builder module project) from Spring MVC portlet,  I read through forums link https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/service-trackers and tried to use Service Tracker to access service from Controller.

here's SpringTestPortletViewController.java

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("VIEW")
public class SpringTestPortletViewController {

    private FooServiceTracker fooServiceTracker;
    @PostConstruct 
    public void init(){
         fooServiceTracker=new FooServiceTracker(this); 
         fooServiceTracker.open(); 
    }
    @PreDestroy public void destroy(){ 
         fooServiceTracker.close(); 
    }

    @RenderMapping
    public String question(Model model) {
        try {
            if(!fooServiceTracker.isEmpty()){
                FooLocalService fooLocalService=fooServiceTracker.getService();
                fooLocalService.saveFoo(); 
                System.out.println("----" + FooLocalServiceUtil.getFoosCount());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "SpringTest/view";
    }
}
```

FooServiceTracker.java

```
public class FooServiceTracker extends ServiceTracker<FooLocalService,FooLocalService>{

    public FooServiceTracker(Object host){
        super(FrameworkUtil.getBundle(host.getClass()).getBundleContext(), FooLocalService.class, null);
    }
}
```

Facing below issue, during deployment of Spring MVC Portlet. It is unable to get bundle i.e. `FrameworkUtil.getBundle(SpringTestPortletViewController.getClass())`  is coming null

```
11:49:48,432 INFO  [Refresh Thread: Equinox Container: 6095db50-baf9-0016-1a03-97f126c9b821][PortletHotDeployListener:202] Registering portlets for SpringTest-portlet
11:49:48,649 ERROR [Refresh Thread: Equinox Container: 6095db50-baf9-0016-1a03-97f126c9b821][DispatcherPortlet:279] Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springTestPortletViewController': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:408)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
    at org.springframework.web.portlet.FrameworkPortlet.createPortletApplicationContext(FrameworkPortlet.java:368)
    at org.springframework.web.portlet.FrameworkPortlet.initPortletApplicationContext(FrameworkPortlet.java:297)
    at org.springframework.web.portlet.FrameworkPortlet.initPortletBean(FrameworkPortlet.java:271)
    at org.springframework.web.portlet.GenericPortletBean.init(GenericPortletBean.java:124)
    at javax.portlet.GenericPortlet.init(GenericPortlet.java:136)
    at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.init(InvokerPortletImpl.java:296)
    at com.liferay.portlet.PortletInstanceFactoryImpl.init(PortletInstanceFactoryImpl.java:294)
    at com.liferay.portlet.PortletInstanceFactoryImpl.create(PortletInstanceFactoryImpl.java:193)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletInstanceFactoryUtil.create(PortletInstanceFactoryUtil.java:49)
    at com.liferay.portlet.PortletBagFactory.create(PortletBagFactory.java:217)
    at com.liferay.portal.service.impl.PortletLocalServiceImpl.initWAR(PortletLocalServiceImpl.java:858)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:153)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanAopProxy.invoke(ServiceBeanAopProxy.java:174)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy123.initWAR(Unknown Source)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.service.PortletLocalServiceUtil.initWAR(PortletLocalServiceUtil.java:327)
    at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.PortletHotDeployListener.doInvokeDeploy(PortletHotDeployListener.java:210)
    at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.PortletHotDeployListener.invokeDeploy(PortletHotDeployListener.java:95)
    at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.HotDeployImpl.doFireDeployEvent(HotDeployImpl.java:237)
    at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.HotDeployImpl.fireDeployEvent(HotDeployImpl.java:104)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.hot.HotDeployUtil.fireDeployEvent(HotDeployUtil.java:28)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PluginContextListener.fireDeployEvent(PluginContextListener.java:164)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PluginContextListener.doPortalInit(PluginContextListener.java:154)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.BasePortalLifecycle.portalInit(BasePortalLifecycle.java:44)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.PortalLifecycleUtil.register(PortalLifecycleUtil.java:74)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.PortalLifecycleUtil.register(PortalLifecycleUtil.java:58)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.BasePortalLifecycle.registerPortalLifecycle(BasePortalLifecycle.java:54)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PluginContextListener.contextInitialized(PluginContextListener.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.SecurePluginContextListener.contextInitialized(SecurePluginContextListener.java:151)
    at com.liferay.portal.osgi.web.wab.extender.internal.adapter.ServletContextListenerExceptionAdapter.contextInitialized(ServletContextListenerExceptionAdapter.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor487.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.registration.ListenerRegistration$EventListenerInvocationHandler.invoke(ListenerRegistration.java:132)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy491.contextInitialized(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.context.ContextController.doAddListenerRegistration(ContextController.java:359)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.context.ContextController.addListenerRegistration(ContextController.java:312)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.customizer.ContextListenerTrackerCustomizer.addingService(ContextListenerTrackerCustomizer.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.customizer.ContextListenerTrackerCustomizer.addingService(ContextListenerTrackerCustomizer.java:1)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(ServiceTracker.java:941)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(ServiceTracker.java:1)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackAdding(AbstractTracked.java:256)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.track(AbstractTracked.java:229)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.serviceChanged(ServiceTracker.java:901)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:917)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:862)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:801)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:482)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:1001)
    at com.liferay.portal.osgi.web.wab.extender.internal.WabBundleProcessor.initListeners(WabBundleProcessor.java:526)
    at com.liferay.portal.osgi.web.wab.extender.internal.WabBundleProcessor.init(WabBundleProcessor.java:153)
    at com.liferay.portal.osgi.web.wab.extender.internal.WebBundleDeployer._initWabBundle(WebBundleDeployer.java:186)
    at com.liferay.portal.osgi.web.wab.extender.internal.WebBundleDeployer.doStart(WebBundleDeployer.java:106)
    at com.liferay.portal.osgi.web.wab.extender.internal.WabFactory$WABExtension.start(WabFactory.java:163)
    at org.apache.felix.utils.extender.AbstractExtender.createExtension(AbstractExtender.java:259)
    at org.apache.felix.utils.extender.AbstractExtender.modifiedBundle(AbstractExtender.java:232)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker$Tracked.customizerModified(BundleTracker.java:482)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker$Tracked.customizerModified(BundleTracker.java:1)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.track(AbstractTracked.java:232)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker$Tracked.bundleChanged(BundleTracker.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:905)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEventPrivileged(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:165)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEvent(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEvent(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor.publishModuleEvent(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.publishEvent(Module.java:461)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:454)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer.applyDelta(ModuleContainer.java:717)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer.resolveAndApply(ModuleContainer.java:491)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer.resolve(ModuleContainer.java:437)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer.refresh(ModuleContainer.java:955)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerWiring.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1336)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerWiring.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.service.tracker.FooServiceTracker.<init>(FooServiceTracker.java:11)
    at SpringTest.SpringTestPortletViewController.init(SpringTestPortletViewController.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:354)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:305)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:133)
    ... 98 more
```

Appreciate some inputs here,

Comment: In case anyone following this post, can also look for response here https://web.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/86461097

Answer (score 0):

FrameworkworkUtil implementation relies on OSGI runtime to load the classes. I believe your class was not loaded by an OSGi bundle classloader, instead its on a AppClassLoader. The getBundle returns only the classes loaded via OSGI classloader and thus its returning NULL. Please refer to `org.osgi.framework.launch.FrameworkFactory` docs to know more about configuring the OSGI runtime.

Comment: agreed, but that is how its mentioned in https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/service-trackers. I was looking for a way to resolve dependency of service builder generated jar from Spring MVC portlet.

Answer (score 0):

I moved the service builder module api jars in tomcat/lib/ext restarted the server and then accessed the Util class in Spring MVC portlet it worked. 
But need some direction here for the best practices, to handle such dependencies of service builder module jars in Spring MVC portlet ?

Answer (score 0):

The general practice I have followed in my experience has been to maintain generic service builder jars like custom user services, etc under tomcat/lib/ and keep the portlet specific service builder jars under portlet's WEB-INF/lib/. Also, if there is a need to share a builder jars, still put them under portlet WEB-INF/lib and use `required-deployment-contexts` to refer the jar in the different portlet context.

Comment: Thanks uday it use to work till 6.2, but does putting module jar in portlet's WEB-INF/lib/ or using required-deployment-contexts to specify module api project work in DXP Spring MVC portlet ? As the context are different for Spring Portlet i.e WAB and OSGi Module for service builder ?